Calculate Means and SDs for each column using dplyr´s "summarise_all"
I have a large dataset, containing a categorical (Size) and a numeric variable(Fraktion) to group the data. The rest are analytical resultd like numeric values. Every value got sampled 3 times, and I needed to create the meaning.
It looks more or less like this:



Size
Fraktion
Sample
Value1
Value2
...




A
1
1
3
2
...


A
1
2
4
4
...


A
1
3
2
1
...


A
2
1
1
5
...


A
2
2
3
7
...


A
2
3
4
5
...


B
1
1
2
3
...


B
1
2
3
2
...


B
1
3
4
2
...


B
1
3
2
4
...



To calculate the means of the samples I used the summarise function of dyplr like this:
mean_df<-
  df %>%
  group_by(Fraktion,Size)%>%
  summarise_all("mean")

I guess this might not be the most elegant way, as in the next step I have to remove the "Sample" column, but it worked for me. Now I want to integrate the standard deviation for each created mean and add it to the df.
I found this thread ((Can I calculate the standard error of all columns with the "summarise_all" function in R dplyr)and tried to use the code provided by Ronak Shah in answer 3:
mean_sd_df<-
  df %>%
  group_by(Fraktion, Size)%>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean,sd,se=sd(.)/sqrt(n())))

However, I get the follwoing error:
across() must only be used inside dplyr verbs. Any idea what could be the issue?

The classic tidyverse way to do this, is first make your data tidy by pivoting your table to long format:
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Value"), names_to = "Measurement", values_to = "val")

and then summarize this long table:
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Value"), names_to = "Measurement", values_to = "val") %>%
  group_by(Fraktion, Size) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(val), se = sd(val)/sqrt(n()))

If you want the summary by "ValueX", add the name of the new column to the grouping:
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Value"), names_to = "Measurement", values_to = "val") %>%
  group_by(Fraktion, Size, Measurement) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(val), se = sd(val)/sqrt(n())) 


Managed to solve ist with this, thanks a lot for the answer :)

You can do this by passing the list of functions to across in summarise (which is the new recommended way instead of summarise_each/summarise_all). This allows you to de-select Sample as well:
library(tidyverse)


df <- tibble::tribble(
          ~Size, ~Fraktion, ~Sample, ~Value1, ~Value2,
          "A",         1,       1,       3,       2,
          "A",         1,       2,       4,       4,
          "A",         1,       3,       2,       1,
          "A",         2,       1,       1,       5,
          "A",         2,       2,       3,       7,
          "A",         2,       3,       4,       5,
          "B",         1,       1,       2,       3,
          "B",         1,       2,       3,       2,
          "B",         1,       3,       4,       2,
          "B",         1,       3,       2,       4
        )


df |>
  group_by(Size, Fraktion) |>
  summarise(across(-Sample, .fns = list(
    mean = mean,
    sd = sd,
    se = ~ sd(.x) / sqrt(n())
  )))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Size'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 3 × 8
#> # Groups:   Size [2]
#>   Size  Fraktion Value1_mean Value1_sd Value1_se Value2_mean Value2_sd Value2_se
#>   <chr>    <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 A            1        3        1         0.577        2.33     1.53      0.882
#> 2 A            2        2.67     1.53      0.882        5.67     1.15      0.667
#> 3 B            1        2.75     0.957     0.479        2.75     0.957     0.479

This keeps it in the 'wide' format like your input data. Pivot longer as suggested in the other answer is also a helpful step if the longer shape suits your uses better.

Thanks for the answer, looks like this is exactly what I need. However, I get an error stating that I 'across' is only usable in dplyr verbs, and '|>' is marked as unexpected token?
